# Делегаты в C#. Как и где можно использовать MulticastDelegate?

Tags: c#, делегаты

Изучаю C# и столкнулся с MulticastDelegate. Как и зачем их использовать? И также почему event'ы является делегатами, а не отдельной сущностью.

Comment: Здесь принято задавать только 1 вопрос на 1 пост, учтите на будущее. Если вопрос решен, чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MulticastDelegate` ([ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.multicastdelegate))

> Представляет групповой делегат, то есть делегат, имеющий в своем списке вызовов более одного элемента.

Грубо говоря добавляя более одного метода в делегат вы делаете его мультикастом.

```
myDelegate = Method1;
myDelegate += Method2;
myDelegate(); // вызовется сначала Method1, затем Method2
```

---

События это частный случай делегатов, они не "почему" делегаты, они просто делегаты. Разница только в доступности вызвать этот делегат.

Например вот 2 варианта

```
public MyClass
{
    public event Action MyEvent;
    public Action MyDelegate;
}
```

И вот разница

```
var instance = new MyClass();
instance.MyDelegate(); // работает
instance.MyEvent(); // ошибка
```

То есть за пределами кода класса событие вызвать нельзя. Больше ничем события от любых других делегатов не отличаются.

Еще события можно делать свойствами с методами `add/remove`, очень похоже на `get/set` обычных свойств, только для подписывания `+=` и отписывания `-=`. Требуется для пробрасывания внутренних событий, например из классов, которые вы не можете изменять, наружу, при необходимости вклиниваясь в логику добавления и удаления обработчиков события.

```
private event Action myEvent; // здесь кстати event указывать необязательно

public event Action MyEvent // а здесь обязательно
{
    add => myEvent += value;
    remove => myEvent -= value;
}
```

С делегатами такое вытворять нельзя, но можете пока не обращать на этот маленький нюанс внимания.

Подробнее о том, зачем так сделано с событиями, можно почитать в описании шаблона проектирования Издатель/Подписчик (Publisher/Subscriber).

Comment: "Больше ничем события от любых других делегатов не отличаются", отличаются. У событий есть `add` и `remove` методы

Comment: @Aarnihauta добавил, спасибо

Comment: @aepot

Спасибо вам большое)

Comment: @aepot Очень вам благодарен, спасибо вам за информацию